# AWS EC2 with and without EMR and Spark will not SSH to Port 22

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mac-osx, amazon-emr

I'm on a MacBookPro. I tried starting an EC2 instance with EMR and Rstudio and Spark. I got a port 22 time out. I asked AWS for help and took down my firewall and restarted my modem. Still, nothing but port 22 timeout.

AWS managed to get one EC2 instance running. Then another. Still, I could not ssh on port 22. I changed the vpc, subnet, security group, etc. Amazon verified that they were correct. I allowed all traffic on IPv4. Still, I could not connect via SSH port 22. I unloaded and launched the plist. I checked another file in nano that clearly said port 22 was for ssh. In fact, it listed all of the ports and their functions. I've read every page on the web.

It has now been two, yes, two weeks, and I am on the edge. What else is there to do except begin litigating the bill I've racked up with AWS and give up?

Comment: We need technical information to help you. Suggest you start with the basics, an tutorial on how to set up a basic Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance and SSH into it. That is clearly something that works as millions of people have done it. If you can't SSH in it's either your VPC configuration or your home network. Try a different computer on a different network to see if it's your home network / firewall. If neither computer work it's probably your VPC. Post screenshots of VPC, subnets, routing, IGW etc and we might be able to help. Or pay a professional for help.

Comment: What command are you running to SSH? What errors do you get?